# How to extract hour and mention by AM or PM from TimeStamp using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, rdbms

I have a table called Transaction. One of the field name is Time which is TimeStamp datatype. So the result will be like this `2015-01-17 08:12:48.000`

Now I want to separate hours and followed by AM PM like

```
2015-01-17 08:12:48.000       8AM
2015-01-17 15:12:48.000       3PM
```

I separate an hour using this code `CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),RIGHT(Time,7),108) hour` and got an output like `8`. How to mention AM/PM?

Comment: @akhterAlaminFarhan Thanks for response, But you have given only time. In my case it has date and time as well. your code it doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure the field is of type TimeStamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the next Code:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(ColumnName AS DATETIME),'hh tt')
```

**Example:**

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST('2015-01-17 08:12:48.000' AS DATETIME),'hh tt') Time
union all 
SELECT FORMAT(CAST('2015-01-17 15:12:48.000' AS DATETIME),'hh tt')
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Update:**

For removing leading zeroes:

There are two approaches:-

**Hardest One:-**

use the next code:

```
SELECT substring(convert(varchar(5), FORMAT(CAST('2015-01-17 08:12:48.000' AS DATETIME),'hh tt'), 108), patindex('%[^0]%',convert(varchar(5), FORMAT(CAST('2015-01-17 08:12:48.000' AS DATETIME),'hh tt'), 108)), 10)  Time
union all 
SELECT substring(convert(varchar(5), FORMAT(CAST('2015-01-17 15:12:48.000' AS DATETIME),'hh tt'), 108), patindex('%[^0]%',convert(varchar(5), FORMAT(CAST('2015-01-17 15:12:48.000' AS DATETIME),'hh tt'), 108)), 10)
```

**Simplist One:-** (via *[David Dubois](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1008646/david-dubois)*)

Use the next format `h tt` as following:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(ColumnName AS DATETIME),'h tt')
```

Example:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST('2015-01-17 08:12:48.000' AS DATETIME),'h tt') Time
union all 
SELECT FORMAT(CAST('2015-01-17 15:12:48.000' AS DATETIME),'h tt')
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: If we don't want a leading zero, why not format using 'h tt'?

Comment: @DavidDubois an amazing comment, thanks sir, the answer has been updated.